# OSX Lion fullscreen code editor?

Tags: macos, editor, fullscreen, osx-lion

Since I'm working on an 11" Air I was wondering if there are any good code editors yet that take advantage of Lion's fullscreen mode (or whatever it's called).

Please share if you have found such code editors, thanks! I'm writing mostly JS, CSS & HTML. And a little PHP.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), or its freeware younger brother [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: Thanks, I read from BBEdit's website that it supports fullscreen mode under Lion. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I love BBEdit and have been using it for many years - I don't do CSS & HTML but apparently it has a lot of useful features for working on that kind of thing - I don't think you'll be disappointed !

Comment: I tried it and it seems like it has everything I wanted from a code editor, except one thing - I can't figure out how to work directly on a server, like on Espresso or Dreamweaver. Sorry for the offtopic, but a little tip would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not in front of my Mac just now but I do know that BBEdit lets you open/save files directly via FTP/SFTP - take a look at the File menu...

Answer (score 1):

You can give Maximizer a try and then use any code editor you like.   http://chpwn.com/apps/maximizer.html

Just mentioning this for the sake of posterity.

Or you can wait for the next release of TextMate, sometime in early 2053. (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is my favorite editor. It is available of all platforms (windows, mac, linux), has great plugins and comes with "full-screen" and "distraction-free" editing mode, which will be great for your current setup.